# "can not get class data for sun/java2d/Disposer"

Tags: java, exception, visualvm, jmap, hprof

I have used a script successfully in the past and the JDK did not change, but for some reason in this instance I was unable to convert a core dump to a hprof;

```
Attaching to core my.core from executable /opt/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.31-b07
Dumping heap to my.hprof ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AssertionFailure: can not get class data for sun/java2d/Disposer$$Lambda$10x00000001002e8428
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.Assert.that(Assert.java:32)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.writeInstance(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:803)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AbstractHeapGraphWriter$1.doObj(AbstractHeapGraphWriter.java:95)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.ObjectHeap.iterateLiveRegions(ObjectHeap.java:353)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.ObjectHeap.iterate(ObjectHeap.java:171)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AbstractHeapGraphWriter.write(AbstractHeapGraphWriter.java:51)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.write(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:433)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.run(HeapDumper.java:62)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.main(HeapDumper.java:83)
    ... 6 more
```

The Partial heap won't load with visualvm.

What could cause this?
Is this a known bug?
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug and has been fixed starting with Java 8 Update 60.

See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8044416

Java 8 ticket: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077507